# Calculation of $\frac{d\lambda}{dt}$ under volume preserving mean curvature flow

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

I want to calculate the $\frac{d\lambda}{dt}$ under volume preserving mean curvature flow. $\lambda$ is first eigenvalue of Laplacain i.e.
\begin{align}
-\Delta u &=\lambda(t) u  ~~~~~~~~~~~in ~~\Omega_t  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~&(1)  \\
u|_{\partial\Omega_t}&=0    &(2)  \\
\int_{\Omega_t} u^2  &=1       &(3)
\end{align}
$\Delta$ is Euclidian Laplacian.   $\Omega_t$ is the domain enclosed by $M_t$.  The notation can be found in picture below or in 
*Huisken, Gerhard*, [**The volume preserving mean curvature flow**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.1987.382.35), J. Reine Angew. Math. 382, 35-48 (1987). [ZBL0621.53007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0621.53007).

I try two ways to calculate $\frac{d\lambda}{dt}$, but I get different results.And fail to find my mistake.

**First way**, differential $(1)$, I have
$$
-\Delta(\partial_t u)=\partial_t \lambda u + \lambda \partial_t u
$$
multiply $u$ in two side and integral
$$
-\int_{\Omega_t} u \Delta(\partial_t u) =\partial_t \lambda +\int_{\Omega_t} \lambda u\partial_t u
$$
although $\Omega_t$ is changing, but from $(3)$, I have 
$$
\int_{\Omega_t} u\partial_t u =0
$$
Then, 
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega_t} u\Delta(\partial_t u ) &=-\int_{\Omega_t} \nabla u\cdot \nabla(\partial_t u)  \\
&=-\int_{\partial \Omega_t}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu} \partial_t u
+ \int_{\Omega_t} \Delta u \partial_t u  \\
&=-\int_{\partial \Omega_t}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu} \partial_t u
\end{align}
so, I have 
$$
\partial_t\lambda =\int_{\partial \Omega_t}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu} \partial_t u
$$

**Second way**, we know 
$$
\lambda=\int_{\Omega_t} |\nabla u|^2=\int_S\int_0^{|F(x,t)|} |\nabla u|^2\rho^n d\rho dx
$$
$S$ is n-dim sphere, and I asuume origin is in $\Omega_t$. Then 
\begin{align}
\partial_t \lambda  &= \int_S |\nabla u |^2 |F|^n \partial_t|F| dx+\int_S\int_0^{|F(x,t)|} 2\nabla u\nabla(\partial_tu)\rho^n d\rho dx  \\
&=\int_{\partial\Omega_t}|\nabla u|^2 \partial_t|F| + 2\int_{\Omega_t} \nabla u\nabla u_t   \\
&=\int_{\partial\Omega_t}|\nabla u|^2 (h-H)\frac{F\cdot \nu}{|F|}
+2\int_{\partial\Omega_t} u_t \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}
-2\int_{\Omega_t }\Delta u u_t  \\
&=\int_{\partial\Omega_t}|\nabla u|^2 (h-H)\frac{F\cdot \nu}{|F|}
+2\int_{\partial\Omega_t} u_t \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}
\end{align}

I feel they are not equal, so at least one is wrong. Where is it?  Besides, this question is a little long, if there are any thing which is unclear, please ask me . Thanks.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> [image]